# Method for converting PNGs to premultiplied alpha

Tags: png, imagemagick, python-imaging-library, premultiplied-alpha

Looking for some kind of simple tool or process for *Windows* that will let me convert one or more standard PNGs to premultiplied alpha.

Command line tools are ideal; I have easy access to PIL (Python Imaging Library) and Imagemagick, but will install another tool if it makes life easier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just released a bit of code in Python and in C that does what you are looking for. It's on github: http://github.com/maxme/PNG-Alpha-Premultiplier

The Python version is based on the cssndrx response. C version is based on libpng.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. :) Going with this answer because I find the code easier to understand than madlag's example, though perhaps not as clever.

Comment: I like the fact that his code checks if the image is premultiplied.  Not requested by the OP but still very nice.

Comment: No wonder the python version is slow - you loop over every single pixel. Francois' python solution is much faster.

Answer (score 17):

Using ImageMagick, as requested:

```
convert in.png -write mpr:image -background black -alpha Remove mpr:image -compose Copy_Opacity -composite out.png
```

Thanks @mf511 for the update.

Comment: This doesn't preserve the alpha channel, it just multiplies all the channels with alpha and then seems to discard alpha entirely. I tried this on ImageMagick 7.0.5-4 Q16.

Comment: Yes, but that worked before. Use this as alternative: `convert in.png -background black -alpha Remove in.png -compose Copy_Opacity -composite out.png`

Comment: The second command works great! Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

A more complete version of the cssndrx answer, using slicing in numpy to improve speed:

```
import Image
import numpy

im = Image.open('myimage.png').convert('RGBA')
a = numpy.fromstring(im.tostring(), dtype=numpy.uint8)
alphaLayer = a[3::4] / 255.0
a[::4]  *= alphaLayer
a[1::4] *= alphaLayer
a[2::4] *= alphaLayer

im = Image.fromstring("RGBA", im.size, a.tostring())
```

Et voila !

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to do this through PIL. Here is a rough outline of the steps:

1) Load the image and convert to numpy array

```
    im = Image.open('myimage.png').convert('RGBA')
    matrix = numpy.array(im)
```

2) Modify the matrix in place. The matrix is a list of lists of the pixels within each row. Pixels are represented as [r, g, b, a]. Write your own function to convert each [r, g, b, a] pixel to the [r, g, b] value you desire.

3) Convert the matrix back to an image using

```
    new_im = Image.fromarray(matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PIL only:

```
def premultiplyAlpha(img):
    # fake transparent image to blend with
    transparent = Image.new("RGBA", img.size, (0, 0, 0, 0))
    # blend with transparent image using own alpha
    return Image.composite(img, transparent, img)
```